# Is there a standard way to breakdown huge optimization models to ensure the submodules are working correctly?

Tags: testing, optimization, design-patterns

Apologies as this may be a general question for optimization:

For truly large scale optimization models it feels as if the model becomes quite complex and cumbersome before it is even testable. For small scale optimization problems, up to even 10-20 constraints its feasible to code the entire program and just stare at it and debug.

However, for large scale models with potentially 10s-100 of constraint equations it feels as if there should be a way to test subsections of the optimization model before putting the entire thing together.

Imagine you are writing a optimization for a rocket that needs to land on the moon the model tells the rocket how to fly itself and land on the moon safely. There might be one piece of the model that would dictate the gravitational effects of the earth and moon and their orbits together that would influence how the rocket should position itself, another module that dictates how the thrusters should fire in order to maneuver the rocket into the correct positions, and perhaps a final module that dictates how to optimally use the various fuel sources.

Is there a good practice to ensure that one small section (e.g the gravitational module) works well independently of the whole model. Then iteratively testing the rocket thruster piece, then the optimal fuel use etc. Since, once you put all the pieces together and the model doesn't resolve (perhaps due to missing constraints or variables) it quickly becomes a nightmare to debug.

What are the best practices if any for iteratively building and testing large-scale optimization models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regularly work on models with millions of variables and equations. ("10s-100 of constraint equations" is considered small-scale). Luckily they all have less than say 50 blocks of similar equations (indexed equations). Obviously just eyeballing solutions is impossible. So we add a lot of checks (also on the data, which can contain errors). For debugging, it is a very good idea to have a very small data set around. Finally, it helps to have good tools, such as modeling systems with type/domain checking, automatic differentiation etc.)

Often we cannot really check equations in isolation because we are dealing with simultaneous equations. The model only makes sense when all equations are present. So "iterative building and testing" is usually not possible for me. Sometimes we keep small stylized models around for documentation and education.